# Parameterizing the data model in an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am implementing a control/widget that has three options, only one of which may be selected, which led me to using radiobuttons. This widget has to appear several times on various forms so I embarked on creating (incrementally) a dedicated directive.

The template of the directive is as follows:

```html
<div class="row">
<span class="fieldlabel col-xs-3">{{title}}</span>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="modelName" value="{{value1}}">
        {{label1}}
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="modelName" value="{{value2}}">
        {{label2}}
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="modelName" value="{{value3}}">
        {{label3}}
    </label>
</div>
```

The title, labels and values are correctly defined/computed either through using the custom directives or in the controller.

The last question I am facing now is how to specify different model bindings for each such widget? All instances of this widget currently share their model binding, which is of course not what I need. For instance, both of the divs in the fictitious example below would bind to "modelName" but I need them to bind to say "annotationsPos" and "menuPos" in the view's controller.

```
<div my-3option-radiobutton title="Show annotations"></div>
<div my-3option-radiobutton title="Menu position"></div>
```

How can I specify bindings in a custom directive?

**EDIT 1**
I think either I haven't really made myself clear or I lack some elements that would have helped me understand the answers that were offered.

If I had written the HTML by hand, I would have had something like this:

```
<div class="row">
<span class="fieldlabel col-xs-3">Position of your annotations</span>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="annotationsPos" value="left">
        Left of the element
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="annotationsPos" value="middle">
        Through the element
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="annotationsPos" value="right">
        Right of the element
    </label>
</div>
<!-- -->
<div class="row">
<span class="fieldlabel col-xs-3">Position of the top menu</span>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="menuPos" value="left">
        Top left
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="menuPos" value="middle">
        Top middle
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="menuPos" value="right">
        Top right
    </label>
</div>
<!-- -->
<div class="row">
<span class="fieldlabel col-xs-3">Position of notifications</span>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="notificationPos" value="left">
        Bottom left
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="notificationPos" value="middle">
        Bottom middle
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="notificationPos" value="right">
        Bottom right
    </label>
</div>
```

Instead of copying and pasting this boilerplate code multiple times, I'm looking to do this thanks to an **attribute** directive:

```
<div my-3option-radiobutton title="Position of your annotations"></div>
<div my-3option-radiobutton title="Position of system notifications"></div>
<div my-3option-radiobutton title="Position of the top menu"></div>
```

What changes between these block is made of titles, values and, **most importantly**, model attribute values. I've covered the titles and values in the directive's controller in a non elegant way (see plunk further below). My problem is that I can't seem to:

1. determine where to specify an ng-model AND
2. have the "generated" HTML code refer correctly to that model attribute value (i.e. 'annotationPos', 'notificationsPos' and 'menuPos') AND
3. have two-way binding with the parent controller

**EDIT 2**
This [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CnoCfdOZ6ujDNuV3fdxF?p=preview) shows that @Suresh's answer is working, with a minor modification concerning the field name. However, the [directive that I have written](http://plnkr.co/edit/4TwKEMTP95xMxcOYD0Xf?p=preview) does not work (all widgets on the page bind to the same value), maybe due to it being an attribute directive and not an element directive. I don't want to have the latter type as it doesn't make sense to me and to top it all, this is to be integrated in an existing larger project, with other developers on it, that uses no element directive. This however does not mean that element directives are never to be used on the project.

Anyway, I'll keep looking for a solution. Thanks.

**EDIT 3**
I have resorted to using an ng-repeat directive in the template, just like @Suresh did. Using a developed template (i.e. repeating the input tag manually) does not work but I don't know whether that has to do with using/not using ng-repeat or rather with the way I "build" the values and labels in the controller.

Lessons learned from my plunk: even with a two-way binding over ngModel (below) in the controller of the widget:

- all controls on the page will bind to the same value/variable unless ng-repeat is used
- the parent controller's bound model is not updated if the template has `data-ng-model="ngModel"` instead of `data-ng-model="$parent.ngModel"`

```js
scope: {
    ngModel: "="
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
app.directive("myRadiobutton", function () {
    var templateHtml = function () {
        return '<div class="form-group" >' +
                 '<label style="margin-right: 10px"; ng-repeat="(key, option) in options.valueList">' +
                         '<input type="radio" name="myfield" ng-value="option.value" ng-model="$parent.ngModel" ng-required="options.required" />{{option.title}}' +
                 '</label>' +
             '</div>';
    };

    return {
        scope: { options: '=', ngModel: '=' },
        required: ['ngModel'],
        restrict: 'E',
        template: templateHtml,
    };
});
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.radioGender =   {
    "label": "Gender",
    "required": true,
    "className": "",
    "valueList": [
      {
        "title": "Male",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "title": "Female",
        "value": "2"
      },
      {
        "title": "Others",
        "value": "3"
      }
    ]

  };
  
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="myController" >
   <my-radiobutton options="radioGender" ng-model="genderValue"></my-radiobutton>
  <span>{{genderValue}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: change the template based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "=" in the directive scope to bind an object:

```
directives.directive("dirname", function () {
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         replace: false,
         scope: {
             model: '=', // pass a referecne object
             title: '@'  // path as string
         },
         controller: function ($scope, $rootScope) {
             ...
         },

     }
 });


 <div dirname title="Menu Position" model="modelName" ></div>
```